# Ubuntu apps development - how to communicate betwen 2 pages

Tags: application-development

On one Page I have displayed ListView and on child Page I creating new records.
When the child Page is Closed I would like to refresh the ListView.
Is there some Signel which inform me when page get focus or something simmilar ?
It's done in QML using the Page from Ubuntu.Components.

Comment: Could you add your code snippets to your question, it will help us in choosing the right signal to send and where to register it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Connections{
     target: pageStack
     onCurrentPageChanged:{
         if( pageStack.currentPage === mainPage2) {
             print ("back on page mainPage2")

         }
         else {
             print ("exiting page mainPage2")
         }
     }
 }
```